# Relationship fault on RestKit Mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I really don't understand why I have an error :/
Can someone look at it ?

**Json file :**

```
{
"total_count": 3,
"incomplete_results": false,
"winners": [
    {
        "windate": "2015-05-26 17:11:30.0",
        "gift": "foo",
        "email": "foo",
        "giftack": "foo",
        "lastname": "foo",
        "gender": "foo",
        "firstname": "foo",
        "updategiftdate":null
    }
],
"nbWinners": 3
}
```

**Mapping file :**

```
    //Winner List Mapping
RKEntityMapping *winnerListMapping =
    [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"WinnerList"
                        inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
winnerListMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"nbWinners"];
[winnerListMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                    @"total_count" : @"totalCount",
                             @"incomplete_results" : @"incompleteResults",
                                      @"nbWinners" : @"nbWinners" }];

//Winner Mapping
RKEntityMapping *winnerMapping =
    [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Winner"
                        inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
winnerMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"winDate"];
[winnerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
                                            @"windate", @"gift", @"email", @"giftack", @"lastname", @"gender", @"firstname", @"updategiftdate"]];

//Link Winner to WinnerList
[winnerListMapping addPropertyMapping:
    [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"winners"
                                                toKeyPath:@"winners"
                                              withMapping:winnerMapping]];

//Run Mapping
RKResponseDescriptor *winnerListResponseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:winnerListMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:@"example.json"
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)
 ];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:winnerListResponseDescriptor];
```

**Data Model :**

[image]

**And finally :**

```
2015-09-16 10:13:25.018 iDol Check[26031:954937] 
(
    "<WinnerList: 0x7f9d0167f4b0> (entity: WinnerList; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://7E40E0FD-3677-45EA-9BD1-59F755C05BC5/WinnerList/p3> ; data: {\n    incompleteResults = 0;\n    nbWinners = 3;\n    totalCount = 3;\n    winners = \"<relationship fault: 0x7f9d0167afa0 'winners'>\";\n})"
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting this is the error.

```
//Link Winner to WinnerList
[winnerListMapping addPropertyMapping:
    [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"winners"
                                                toKeyPath:@"winners"
                                              withMapping:winnerMapping]];
```

Specifically the `toKeyPath:@"winners"` your Winner model do not have a `winners` attribute.

Comment: relationshipMappingFromKeyPath is a WinnerList attribute and toKeyPath is a json attribute, no ? The aim, is to put the all content of WinnerMapping (many Winner objects) is the WinnerList object. So Winner don't need a winners attribute

Comment: You are right. I noticed a unrecognised selector error "[Winner winners]" and assumed it was that. I'm guessing you already have solved this one, if not the winner mapping looks wrong to me. Maybe that is causing a parsing error. Try using a dictionary the same way as the above winnerListMapping.

Comment: Yes, I solved this one. But it wasn't the real problem ;) I don't really understand why it didn't working but i have changed my way  to do that and now it's working. Thanks :)